# Can the combination of the two models be determinant by the accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, metrics, xgboost

I have two machine learning models

Model 1 predicted a result of 100
Model 2 predicted a result of 90

Model 1 has an accuracy of 30%
Model 2 has an accuracy of 70%

Combined prediction would be (100 * 0.3) + (90 * 0.7) = 93

would this be a viable approach to get the combined predictions of both models?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Comment: Do a google search for "ensemble learning". You'll get plenty of hits.

Answer (score 0):

You may get better results using an ensemble classifier like mentioned above. With that, the classifier generates and optimizes the best combination of multiple models that are created by using different feature combinations. A common one you can use and learn about is a random forest classifier. [This blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-implementation-and-explanation-of-the-random-forest-in-python-77bf308a9b76) has a good explanation and example.